# Can I change what useragent websites detect on my machine?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, download, 32-bit

I am trying to see if there is a way to download a specific type of program from a given website if the site "auto-detects" CPU architecture and downloads the program automatically. I suppose I could do this on a VM, but I would like to do this on my native system. Thanks in advance.

~More specifically, I would like to download the 32-bit installer for [Hitman Pro](https://www.hitmanpro.com/en-us/hmp.aspx) on my 64-bit machine.~

Update: I was able to download the 32-bit installer, but I would still like to know of this is possible on other websites that do not allow the end-user to decide.

Comment: I am confused, the [specific website](https://www.hitmanpro.com/en-us/downloads.aspx) in question, doesn't auto-detect your operating system.  I don't believe that is even possible unless your using a plug-in like Java.  It certainly is not possible with HTML 5 or JavaScript I know that.

Comment: Not the OS, the system architecture (which is based off of the CPU). Websites like Apple are somehow able to determine the host machine processor architecture and automically download a 32-bit installer of iTunes if the machine is 32-bit and vise-versa.

Comment: What you need to do is change the `useragent` string that your browser reports to the website as that is the only information the website is given that can tell it what system you are running. You've not stated what browser you are using so I cannot suggest anything more specific than that except to say that every browser I know has several extensions that will change it for you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see what I can find, as I use several different browsers...

Comment: @Mr.Mendelli - You should clarify your question because that wasn't immediately apparent.  As for the reason I specified, an operating system, that's because you can easily detect what architecture a client is by the OS.

Comment: How about that? I admit I wasn't entierly certain on how to word this. Knowing the term "useragent" beforehand would have made it easier...

Comment: @Mr.Mendelli changing the useragent to something nonsensical per my answer below seems to do the trick. If I try to download the hitman executable on my phone I get `hitman.exe`, if I tell my phone to impersonate Desktop Firefox then I get `hitman_x64.exe`. presumably the non-x64 version is 32-bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way a website identifies you is via your `useragent` string. This string is sent with requests for webpages and contains various information about your system.  [Per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent)

> most Web browsers use a User-Agent string value as follows:
>
> Mozilla/[version] ([system and browser information]) [platform] ([platform details]) [extensions]. For example, Safari on the iPad has used the following:
>
> `Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7B405`

An example user agent string:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0

The WOW64 part identifies the system as 64-bit Windows, WoW64 is the Windows-on-Windows 64 bit subsystem indicating that you have a 32-bit browser on a 64-bit host. If that part were `Win64` then it should be indicating a native 64-bit browser. That section being missing *should* indicate a 32-bit browser, or at least the website should assume it is.

Alternatively many websites will fallback to offering you a list of downloads when they receive an unsupported useragent string. Sending a useragent for a Solaris box for example could make it assume you are downloading the file to use elsewhere.

To indicate a 32-bit operating system, and thus download a 32-bit version of  whatever you need, you would need to edit your useragent string to indicate a 32 bit machine.

Udger.com has a [useragent string list](https://udger.com/resources/ua-list)

Most browsers have a way to edit the useragent string reported to websites and also have extensions that will change it for you. Check the extension store for your browser(s).